# 2 accordion A and B need accordion A first category to also open accordion B first category and viceversa

Tags: html, jquery, angular, bootstrap-4

Hello this is my first question, english is not my native language so sorry if I make some mistake.

I'm using Angular 6, jQuery and BS for my project.

I have two accordions with different categories each. Let's name them A1 and A2.

When i click A1 i want A2 to also open/close, same when i click A2. Is there any way ?

I tried jQuery for this but I get an endless loop

```
$('.A1').on('click', async function() {
        await $(".A2").click();
    });

$('.A2').on('click', async function() {
        await $(".A1").click();
    });
```

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vwBU.png)

Thanks in advance to anyone who can answer this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by calling the `toggle` method on the expansion panel of the accordion. Give each of your expansion panel an id and call toggle on it.

Here is the [Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bk5ypb?file=src/app/expansion-overview-example.html)

```
<mat-accordion >
<!-- #docregion basic-panel -->
<!-- #docregion hide-toggle -->
  <mat-expansion-panel hideToggle #first (click)="second.toggle()">
<!-- #enddocregion hide-toggle -->
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
       This is the first Expansion panel
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        First Content
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>First Content</p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
<!-- #enddocregion basic-panel -->
 
</mat-accordion>
<br/>

<mat-accordion>
<!-- #docregion basic-panel -->
<!-- #docregion hide-toggle -->
  <mat-expansion-panel #second hideToggle (click)="first.toggle()"> 
<!-- #enddocregion hide-toggle -->
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
       This is the second Expansion panel
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        Second Content
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p> Second Content</p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
<!-- #enddocregion basic-panel -->
 
</mat-accordion>
```